# Auto Layout in iOS 6 Beta

Tags: ios, ios6, autolayout

Auto Layout was announced in iOS 6 but I've been having difficulty finding any information or documentation about it. How exactly is it used? Does it use NSLayoutConstraint? Are there any resources available?

Comment: The reason why you've been having difficulty finding any documentation about it is probably because Apple is still working on it, just like they're still working on iOS 6 itself.

Comment: in this post you will find use full stuffs how auto layout works https://slicode.com/auto-layout-in-ios-explained-in-details-from-basics-part-1/

Answer (score 9):

If Auto Layout in iOS 6 turns out to be anything like Cocoa Auto Layout in Mac OSX 10.7, the [Cocoa Auto Layout Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH1-SW1), a publicly available document, may give you an idea of how it would work in Cocoa Touch.

The underlying engine used by Cocoa Touch is [Cassowary](http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/constraints/cassowary/), and it's also used in other toolkits, such as [enaml](http://docs.enthought.com/enaml/).  I recently wrote a [brief overview of Cassowary, with a comparison between Cocoa Touch and enaml](http://stacks.11craft.com/cassowary-cocoa-autolayout-and-enaml-constraints.html) wherein I port a Cocoa Auto Layout example to Python and enaml.

Comment: Also, I'd highly recommend watching the WWDC 2012 videos on this topic, which cover auto layout on iOS in depth: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/

Comment: A sure source which often people dont look at.
Everyone should be see these videos at least once.