# iOS Development Simulator view squashed

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, xcode4

I have just started iOS programming and am following a tutorial on iTunesU from Stanford.

In the first tutorial we were shown how to build a simple RPN calculator. When I built and compiled in the simulator launched as normal but everything was "squashed". I figured this was because the View in XCode is bigger than the iOS simulator. How can I resize the view in Xcode or am I missing something. 
Here is the iOS simuator view compared with the one from xcode
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you adding controls programmatically or via interface builder ?

Comment: If you're using IB, try turning off auto-layout just to test. Looks like auto-layout is squashing your buttons since you're going from a 4-inch screen in IB to a 3.5-inch simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your view in Xcode's Interface Builder is a 4" view, and the simulator is running a 3.5" device. You can change either one.

The view size in Xcode is changeable by selecting the entire view, and in the attributes inspector, you can change the size between Freeform, 3.5, 4.

You can change the device in the simulator by going to Hardware>Device> Select your device

However, the overlapping buttons, etc, are more related to using Auto Layout, or misused struts. You can either turn off Auto Layout and use struts, or take the challenge to learn Auto Layout. 
Here's a start for Auto Layout: [What is Auto Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424248/what-is-auto-layout)

Answer (score 0):

It's not 'squashed' you are using the device simulator for the latest iPhone, which has a 4 inch display instead of 3.5 inch. To change device go to Hardware->Device in the simulator bar. And the iPhone frame does not show in the latest version of the simulator so to press the home button you go under Hardware->Home.