# App support the app Landscape and portrait mode in both ipad and iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

In my app i trying create a Interface builder supports both Landscape and portrait in ipad and iPhone.

[In Android we used fill parent to autoresize dynamically created UI-Elements.is there any syntax in iOS to autoresizing]

1. How to UI-elements create dynamically supports both Landscape mode and portrait mode?
2. How create the view controller to support the Landscape mode and portrait mode?
3. Is there required to create a all views and UI-elements dynamically?

Comment: use autoresizing mask for this or you can go http://www.raywenderlich.com/50319/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2

Answer (score 2):

1)If you will make xib or nib than develop xib or nib in only one mode as portrait or landscape. Than use Autoresizing option as below Image for any control.

[image: Auto layout]

http://www.raywenderlich.com/50319/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2. You can use this link for auto layout.

But Auto layout is not work properly as you want. so u need to set frames of control pro grammatically evenif u r using autolayout.

2) And If you want to develop dynamically than using below code you can set frame of all controls.
In **ViewwillAppear**.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

in **viewdidload**
set your controls as below.

```
UILabel lbl - [UILabel alloc]init];


-(void)orientationChanged{

       if(Orientation is portrait){
            [lbl setFrame:for portrait];
    }else{
           [lbl setFrame: for landscape];
    }
```

If device change mode than above notification fire and in that method. you can set frame of control.

I hope you will get your answer.

Comment: what i have to implement with in orientationChanged method

Comment: You have to change frame of controls. If portrait than set it and if landscape than set it. Got it.?

Comment: My question is how to create the UI-elements dynamically to support both Land scape and portrait mode

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto - layout for providing both the portrait and landscape mode.

For more details, check this : [What is Auto Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424248/what-is-auto-layout).

You have to set the constraints for landscape and portrait mode to work. Like if you want a button at the top, you can set constraints on it : from top and left  and so on.

If you want a UI element to work change dynamically, you just need to change frame on orientation as per your requirement. Sample code is here :

```
# pragma mark - Orientation related methods

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0)
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        [self deviceRotatedToLandscapeMode];
    }
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [self deviceRotatedToLandscapeMode];
    }
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        [self deviceRotatedToPortraitMode];
    }
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        [self deviceRotatedToPortraitMode];
    }

}

- (void) deviceRotatedToPortraitMode {

    self.mTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

}

- (void) deviceRotatedToLandscapeMode {

    self.mTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.height);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The most reliable approach** -
Create a method in your view controller -

```
-(void)setFrameForOrientationChange:(UIDeviceOrientation*) o {
//... 
 implement your code for frame settings..
}
```