# Autolayout make design according to screen size ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, ios-autolayout

[image]

Hi Guys I want to make design according to screen size. For example My whole design uses autoresizingmask, but now I want use AutoLayout

For example I want red view Leading Trailing and bottom and top space value decrease and increase according to screen size. same as width and height of UIView also decrease and increase according to screen size

How can I do that ?
I am trying to set Leading space, Trailing space, Top Space, Bottom Space, Width, Heigh, Constraints I can not get Idea

How do i achieve ?

Comment: recommend you to read this article, to understand more about autolayout and constraints https://www.raywenderlich.com/160527/auto-layout-tutorial-ios-11-getting-started

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Auto Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424248/what-is-auto-layout)

Comment: You can set constraint like **1.** Leading, Bottom, Trailing, Equal Height of View and need to change multiplier from 1 to 0.64 or as you want. **2.** Bottom, Centre Horizontal Of View, Equal Width of View and change equal width multiplier from 1 to 0.9, Equal Height of View and need to change multiplier from 1 to 0.64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to setting constraints to leading, trailing , top or bottom , when you set height/width make it proportional for example say you have a side menu on the left don't give it explicit width like 200/300 but make it's width Equal to view's  width and set multiplier to say 0.5 if you want to make it take half screen width in any screen width , same applies for height ,also use size classes if you want to configure a constraint in a different way say on iPad or any size class you select

//

you can set multiplier for any constraint if it makes sense to , say leading of a view is 50 like the red one below , when you make multipiler of blue view ' leading 2 it will be 100 , use it when there is a value if 50 was zero then setting multiplier to anything won't change the leading of the setted view

[image]

[image]

Comment: I got it 
can i set top, Bottom, Trailing, Leading Multiplier ?

Comment: I got it according to your Image if I set Multiplier 3 then blue leading will be 150

Comment: But Sh_Khan See my question Image I want to set top, bottom, leading, trailing multiplier related to main view that is  superview.

Comment: yes , it will but make sure you set a multpiler to a non zero value as it's multilication in final

Comment: According to your answer I want to decrease or increase Red view leading space value according to screen size how can I achieve it

Comment: you can set top , bottom , trailing as i described above with nonzero values , otherwise center x,y of the view to the parent and give it proportional width&height

Comment: I understand your answer see my answer and let me know if any correction

Answer (score 0):

`leading` and `trailing` space would be much easier than proportional width. 

Also note, connect your view constraint with [SafeAreaLayoutGuide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492404/safe-area-of-xcode-9)

Try this and see:

[image]

Preview with iPhone-X device:

[image]

Comment: Not as a parent view but safe area layout itself, adds a layer for subviews of main view, protecting them from to be clipped by notch, nozel and rounded corners

Answer (score 0):

(1) Red View [image]

I set center x,y of the view to the parent and give it proportional width&height to the parent

(2) Light Grey UIbutton[image]

I set center x,y of the view to the parent and give it proportional width&height to the parent

check let me know if any correction.
Thanks you

Comment: You are almost correct, but what happen when you run this in iPhone-X? check this layout in iPhone-X also. I think bottom view (red) will be covered by voice nozel.

Comment: I check My current code 
when safe area is necessary for iPad Pro 12.9, its shows perfect 
but when safe area is not necessary for iPad Pro 9.7, its does not show perfect