# Autolayout UIView Xcode 6 nib file

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, nib

I have a UIView where I have laid out various subviews using `autolayout`.  I have done this graphically in `interface builder`, the layouts all work properly on the preview for all sizes of devices.

This `UIView subclass` has no code to override any default methods.

I then load this UIView in my UIView controller using the following code:

```
self.view.addSubview(UIView.loadFromNibNamed("SCPortraitCamera"))
self.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.width)
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.height)
self.view.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
self.view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
```

This is done in viewdidLoad.

The UIView displays correctly, however it doesn't look like any of the UIView subviews are using the auto layout constraints set up in interface builder.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean that the UIView displays correctly? Can you attach a screenshot of how the UIView displays in your VC, compared to how it displays in Preview?

Answer (score 0):

There are severals problems:

System cannot create unambiguous layout. (Rule of the thumb - you should create at least 2 constraint for each dimension)

You should not constraint your view to it's own sizes.

After adding subview, you should refer to it, to create relative constraints

You can refer to this guide: [Autolayout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1) 
Or to this question: [What is auto layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127641/auto-layout-in-ios-6-beta/11129597#11129597)

Hope this may help you.